# Curve on a sphere determined by geodesic curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

Is it possible, given an arc-length parametrized curve $\gamma : [0, 1]\to S^2$, and given $\gamma(0), \gamma'(0)$, to show that $\gamma$ depends only on its signed geodesic curvature, and if so is there a "nice" explicit expression for this? Or does one need to work with "higher" derivatives of the curve to determine its properties? It seems like an existence theorem for solutions to an ODE may suffice here, though I'm not sure how to go about implementing this.

Comment: What’s your definition of geodesic curvature?

Comment: The usual one, given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_curvature.

Comment: First, the wikipedia article defines only geodesic curvature and not signed geodesic curvature. Is this an exercise from a book or lecture? You must have learned a definition of signed geodesic curvature that might be easier to use than the one given in the wikipedia article. As for that article, the relevant points are the 2nd and 3rd bullets in the section "Some results involving geodesic curvature".